# how to reuse JDBC Statements and automatic close back resultsets?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

iam working on an project that will have many statements connected to DB
and i want to reuse statements instead of create new one every connect
and the most important thing that i don't want to close every resultset after use

i want to close back resultsets on statement before reuse it

my code look like this

```
ArrayList<Statement> BackStatements = new ArrayList();
int lastStatementIndex = 0;

private Statement GetStatement() throws SQLException {
    Statement SM;
    int MaxStatements = 5;
    if (BackStatements.size() < MaxStatements) {
        SM = Connection.createStatement();
        BackStatements.add(SM);
        lastStatementIndex = BackStatements.size() - 1;
    } else {
        lastStatementIndex = lastStatementIndex + 1;
        if (lastStatementIndex == MaxStatements) {
            lastStatementIndex = 0;
        }
        SM = BackStatements.get(lastStatementIndex);
     /// i want to close resultset generated by SM now and i do this before return this SM
        SM.getResultSet().close();

    }

    System.out.println("Last Index:" + lastStatementIndex + "---- Size:" + BackStatements.size());
    return SM;
}
```

but this method return this error by logger

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet already requested
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to reuse the statement like JDBC Connections in connection pool..!! but your method is inappropriately dealing with it. **Plz correct me if i didn't get you correctly**

Comment: yes you right i want method to reuse statements or general idea to do that

Comment: but you are not sharing your code **how actually the statements are being created ?**

Comment: You should be using a connection pool for this, instead of trying to roll your own. Many vendor JDBC drivers already support this, and there are external packages like Apache DBCP.

Comment: From the [`Statement.getResultSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet--) javadoc: _"Retrieves the current result as a `ResultSet` object. This method should be called only once per result."_ You'd be better of wrapping the statement in a proxy and tracking the result set when it gets requested. Also note that just executing a new statement will also close previous result sets.

Comment: if new statement will close previous result sets then what if i remove this Line SM.getResultSet().close();

Comment: Nobody, including the Javadoc, has said that creating a new `Statement` will close old `ResultSets`. Only closing the old `ResultSet` or the old `Statement` will do that. The problem with `SM.getResultSet().close()` is that you are requesting the result set a second time, exactly as the error message says. You should certainly remove it but you should still close the old result set. But as remarked above you should certainly be using an existing connection pool implementation, rather than trying to roll your own. And you should almost certainly be using `PreparedStatements` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's bad idea in general. Statement is an interface, actual class can be anything JDBC driver returns. 
In general you can not reuse one statement class for another type. For example,
CallableStatement and PreparedStatement (for oracle JDBC) are incompatible.

As for ResultSet, closing it releases database cursor, at least in some scenarios. Postpone of resultSet.close() can negatively affect DB server capacity.

In general, if your JDBC driver supports connection pooling, it's the way to go. In general network round-trip is way more costful than creation of statements.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bad style to me. You can not ensure the oldest Statement (and ResultSet) is not in use anymore when forcefully closing it.

You give no hint where that Exeption happend but i think this could be the the cause.

If you want to use a statement pool, then you should actively give them back after usage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own statement cache you should use the one provided by the driver. For example in the Oracle JDBC thin driver there is an implicit statement cache that will take care of optimizing how statements and cursors are allocated and freed. It needs to be turned on. The doc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/stmtcach.htm#JJDBC28649). To enable it just set the property "**oracle.jdbc.implicitStatementCacheSize**" to a value for example "**10**" which is usually a good size for the statement cache.